# Do glossaries in Weblate have any effect on machine translations?

Tags: weblate

In Weblate it is easy to add terms to glossaries. I was wondering if these glossaries might be "sent" to any of the machine translation services, to increase the quality of the machine translations. Or are they purely to help the human translators?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, there is no such integration - so the glossaries are there purely to help humans.